# How to populate dropdown list in angular from MVC controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have this in mvc controller for countries where i get list of countries:

```
  model.Edit.Countries = new SelectList(manager.GetCountries(), "Id", "Name");
```

My question is how can i send request from angular to get this countries in $scope and then show them in dropdown list ?

Answer (score 0):

Create WebAPI controller

```
namespace Example.api
{
    public class ExampleController : ApiController
    {

        ......

        [HttpGet]
        public List<Countries> GetAll()
        {
            return new SelectList(manager.GetCountries(), "Id", "Name");
        }

        ......

    }
}
```

In `AngularJS` create `service` to get data:

```
app.factory('countryFactory', [
    '$http', function($http) {
        var baseAddress = '/Example/';    // path to your controller
        var url;
        return {
            getAll: function() {
                url = baseAddress + 'GetAll/';
                return $http.get(url);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Use it in `controller`:

```
app.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', 'countryFactory', function ($scope, countryFactory) {

    ......

    countryFactory.getAll().success(function(data) {
        $scope.countries = data     // this is the $scope variable with `countries` list
    }).error(function() {

    })

    ......

}])
```